# Send HTTP/2 request

Tags: go, https, http2, transport

I'm try send HTTP/2 request from Go, but I can't.

```
client := &net.Client{}
request, err := net.NewRequest("GET", someUrl, nil)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

// some headers
// some cookies

client.Transport = &http2.Transport{}

response, err := client.Do(request)
```

If I print dump request

```
dr, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(request, false)
fmt.Println(string(dr))
```

Then it turns out the following

```
GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
// some headers
// some cookies
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm try send HTTP/2 request from Go, but I can't. ...
>
> ```
> dr, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(request, false)
> fmt.Println(string(dr))
> ```
>
> Then it turns out the following
>
> ```
> GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
> // some headers
> // some cookies
> ```

DumpRequest will not print the request as sent on the wire and is specifically not suitable for checking if HTTP/2 is used. The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#DumpRequest) explicitly states:

> DumpRequest returns the given request **in its HTTP/1.x wire representation**. It should only be used by servers to debug client requests. The returned representation is an **approximation only**; some details of the initial request are lost while parsing it into an http.Request. In particular, the **order and case of header field names are lost**. The order of values in multi-valued headers is kept intact. **HTTP/2 requests are dumped in HTTP/1.x form**, not in their original binary representations."

Comment: Wow! But do not know how to check if http2 is being sent..?

Comment: @overtheman: *"But do not know how to check if http2 is being sent..?"* - that's a different question and should be asked separately. This was one was "Why?", i.e. an explanation of why you only see HTTP/1 when using DumpRequest.